# How to prevent "SQL syntax error" when inserting binary image data into MySQL blob field?

Tags: php, mysql, image, mysqli

I need to move an image (blob field) from a MySQL database to another that are located on two different servers.

I tried to get blob field from the first database and I tried to upload the second, but something went wrong (no errors showing, btw).

```php
/* SERVER #1 */
/* connection to server1... */

$sql_u="SELECT PHOTO, PHOTO_NAME FROM database1 WHERE ID='1'";
$query_u = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_u);


$record_u = mysqli_fetch_array($query_u);
$photo = $record_u['PHOTO'];
$photo_name = $record_u['PHOTO_NAME'];



/* SERVER #2 */
/* connection to server2... */

$sql_i = "UPDATE database2 SET PHOTO = '$photo', PHOTO_NAME = '$photo_name' WHERE ID='1'";
$query_i = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_i);
```

I need to update the second database with the BLOB field of the first one. I tried to use base64_encode() but still not work. I think I have to handle the BLOB field in some way, but I don't know how.

PHOTO : BLOB TYPE
PHOTO_NAME : VARCHAR TYPE

Comment: What was the error message when inserting?

Comment: @Dharman: I know, but this is an example. My question is not about injection.

Comment: @KoalaYeung: if I try to encode base64, there is no error showing. If I not use base64, the error is the classic for syntax error, the $photo variable has special chars.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL syntax errors. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: I would certainly argue that your question is about injection. The solution is to use prepared statements and parameterize your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image binary is surely not safe as SQL text. Try to use [prepared statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to prevent string escaping, `base64_encode`, or other conversion. Let the low level libraries handle it for you.

```php
<?php

/* SERVER #1 */
/* connection to server1 as $conn1...  */

$sql_u="SELECT PHOTO, PHOTO_NAME FROM database1 WHERE ID='1'";
$query_u = mysqli_query($conn1, $sql_u);


$record_u = mysqli_fetch_array($query_u);
$record_i = [
  'photo' = $record_u['PHOTO'],
  'photo_name' = $record_u['PHOTO_NAME'],
];



/* SERVER #2 */
/* connection to server2 as $conn2... */

$id = 1;
$sql_i = 'UPDATE database2 SET PHOTO = ?, PHOTO_NAME = ? WHERE ID=?';
$stmt_i = mysqli_prepare($conn2, $sql_i);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt_i, 'bsi', $record_i['photo'], $record_i['photo_name'], $id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt_i);
```

Comment: @Dharman: Not very familiar with the bind_param. Fixed the last parameter.

Comment: @Dharman: I usually use PDO so I didn't know about the `$types` parameter. Thanks for the comment :-)